# rotating a rectangle gives very messy results

Tags: wpf, vb.net, math, .net-4.0, rotation

i use this process to rotate a rect of 4 borders as corners in wpf:

```
    'find the center
    Dim center As New Point(((topRight.Margin.Left - topLeft.Margin.Left) / 2) + topLeft.Margin.Left,
                            ((topLeft.Margin.Top - bottomLeft.Margin.Top) / 2) + bottomLeft.Margin.Top)

    'shift the points to center and calculate the rotation
    Dim tl As Point = getRotatedPoint(New Point(topLeft.Margin.Left - center.X,
                                                topLeft.Margin.Top - center.Y), 1)
    Dim tr As Point = getRotatedPoint(New Point(topRight.Margin.Left - center.X,
                                                topRight.Margin.Top - center.Y), 1)
    Dim bl As Point = getRotatedPoint(New Point(bottomLeft.Margin.Left - center.X,
                                                bottomLeft.Margin.Top - center.Y), 1)
    Dim br As Point = getRotatedPoint(New Point(bottomRight.Margin.Left - center.X,
                                                bottomRight.Margin.Top - center.Y), 1)

    'shift the points back from center and move
    topLeft.Margin = New Thickness(tl.X + center.X, tl.Y + center.Y, 0, 0)
    topRight.Margin = New Thickness(tr.X + center.X, tr.Y + center.Y, 0, 0)
    bottomLeft.Margin = New Thickness(bl.X + center.X, bl.Y + center.Y, 0, 0)
    bottomRight.Margin = New Thickness(br.X + center.X, +br.Y + center.Y, 0, 0)
```

and the getRotatedPoint function is:

```
'rotating the borders
Private Function getRotatedPoint(ByVal pnt As Point, ByVal degrees As Double)
    Dim rAngle As Double = degrees * (Math.PI / 180)
    Dim x As Double = pnt.X * Math.Cos(rAngle) - pnt.Y * Math.Sin(rAngle)
    Dim y As Double = pnt.X * Math.Sin(rAngle) + pnt.Y * Math.Cos(rAngle)
    Return New Point(x, y)
End Function
```

but i get very messy results, i don't know, any thought will be welcomed :)

**edit1**: i changed the getRotatedPoint function to doubles, and added a radian to degree conversion.

**edit2**: corrected radian conversion function.

**edit3**: corrected the center coords, but still some offsetting happens.

**edit4**: here is sample project for testers: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33417300/testapp.zip

Comment: Explain 'messy results'.

Comment: i can't describe exactly the pattern but it looks random to me and doesn't respond to all angle values, ie. angle 1 doesn't do anything but 10 it just rotate around an unknown center and with an unknown amount! you can copy past the code and try it maybe you got a better view than me.

Comment: I can't copy/paste the code, because it isn't a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: See my answer below.  You're assuming '1' means 1 degree.  It doesn't it means 1 radian.

Comment: @kendall-frey: just copy past it in the code page and add 4 borders names topleft, topright, bottom left, bottom right, the code is very simple and the function too, i shift the corners so that rotation is centeredm then calculate the rotation, the revert the shifting i've done.

Comment: @andand: it doesn't matter as i increment the rotation, so if 1 means 1 radian, then it should rotate around center a radian, not an unexpected rotation.

Comment: If you want someone to try to reproduce the problem, you need a SSCCE.

Comment: man is it that hard to just copy past!

Comment: Yes. I honestly can't reproduce your problem with the details you have provided.

Comment: Degree to radian conversion is rad = deg * pi / 180.  Radian to degree conversion is deg = rad * 180 / pi.  If you want to give it degrees, use the first one.  If you want to give it radians, don't use any conversion.

Comment: @Kendall Frey: added a sample project for you.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, it's unclear what you mean by "messy results", so a couple interpretations come to mind:

If you're rotations are incorrect it could be because you're passing the angles in degrees, while the SIN and COS functions are expecting radians.  This seems likely since you are passing your angles as an integer rather than a floating point representation.  If you want to pass them as degrees, convert to radians before passing them along to the trig functions.

Secondly, if by messy results you mean that the code is complicated, you may want to represent your [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) as matrices.  For the 2-D case, you extend your 2-D vectors to 3-D by adding a 1 as the third element.  Your transformations are 3x3 matrices which you can multiply together to create sequences of rotations, scaling, skews, translation, etc.  The resulting transformation can be applied as a vector - matrix multiplications.

**Update:**

This function has some issues:

```
Private Function getRotatedPoint(ByVal pnt As Point, ByVal angle As Integer)
    Dim x As Integer = pnt.X * Math.Cos(angle) - pnt.Y * Math.Sin(angle)
    Dim y As Integer = pnt.X * Math.Sin(angle) + pnt.Y * Math.Cos(angle)
    Return New Point(x, y)
End Function
```

In addition to the issue of the degree / radian confusion, the type conversion between integer and floating point is left to the compiler and .Net framework which may not be consistent with your intentions.  I would rewrite as follows:

```
Private Function getRotatedPoint(ByVal pnt As Point, ByVal radians As Double)
    Dim x As Double = CDbl(pnt.X) * Math.Cos(radians) - CDbl(pnt.Y) * Math.Sin(radians)
    Dim y As Double = CDbl(pnt.X) * Math.Sin(radians) + CDbl(pnt.Y) * Math.Cos(radians)
    Return New Point(CInt(x), CInt(y))
End Function
```

I still recommend using a matrix library to do this, though.  It will let you focus on developing the core functionality of your program rather than debugging and troubleshooting something which has been written and rewritten a large number of times.

**Update 2:**

This is also problematic:

```
Dim center As New Point((topLeft.Margin.Left + topRight.Margin.Left) / 2,
                            (topLeft.Margin.Left + bottomLeft.Margin.Left) / 2)
```

should this not instead be:

```
Dim center As New Point((topLeft.Margin.Left + topRight.Margin.Right) / 2,
                            (topLeft.Margin.Top + bottomLeft.Margin.Bottom) / 2)
```

If I'm wrong then you will need to explain what your topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft and bottomRight values represent in detail sufficient for anybody to help you... see Kendall Frey's comment on [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: see my explanation above in comments, please.

Comment: @bat3a: You may not see it as being particularly complicated, but it could be significantly simplified by using a matrix library to manage these transformations for you.  As for your other point, when you are carelessly converting between integer and floating point values, you can probably expect to see some unanticipated behavior especially where trig functions are involved.

Comment: i already updated the function as you recommended, same results!

Comment: about matrix library any thoughts on that?

Comment: about Update 2 that will not work, i'll draw a pic and post it shortly

Comment: I don't develop much in .Net so I haven't got a specific recommendation for you.  However, you might look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries#.NET_Framework_languages_C.23.2C_F.23_and_VB.NET for a list of possibilities.

Comment: see this for an explanation of the corner borders: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=33830